# Unable to install discord.py in my Ubuntu

Tags: discord.py

$sudo pip install discord.py

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

````
  Using cached discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz (414 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0
  Using cached aiohttp-1.0.5.tar.gz (499 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-whtj67/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-whtj67/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-F_T2Kq
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-whtj67/aiohttp/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-whtj67/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
    RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: Try using `python3` instead of `python` when you run the command

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of python. I assume your current version is Python 2.x.
Pip dropped the support for python 2 because there is already a new version (Python 3).
I recommend you to update your Python!
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu